# How can I get wildcards to work in XPath attribute value matching?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<root>
  <foo>
    <bar type="a whole bunch of stuff, then a magic string: MUPPET" />
    <value>my Muppet value</value>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <bar type="some other stuff, then a different magic string: GREMLIN" />
    <value>my Gremlin value</value>
  </foo>
</root>
```

I'd like to build an XPath query that returns "my Muppet value" (the string) given the magic string "MUPPET".  My guess was:

```
/root/foo[contains(bar/@type,'MUPPET')]/value/text()
```

but that doesn't seem to work.  I'm really not sure whether that `contains(x,y)` operator allows a query as the first parameter.  As a side issue, I'm not sure whether I need the `text()` on the end.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just checked with this Online XPATH Evaluators and it is working fine:

http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx

Comment: You're entirely correct; they sure do! And that answers my question about /text(), too. Must be a problem with IBM's XPath engine in Eclipse. Hrm.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have a namespace issue with your XPath?

Comment: Don't think so; I think it's a problem with IBM's BIRT reporting tool, not the XPath query. If I change the query from "./foo[contains(bar/@type,'MUPPET')]/value/text()" to "." I still get nothing. Certainly "." should match _something_...